How to access resources on a different Active Directory forest using Windows API + Token impersonation?
I have 2 Active Directory setups on my lab:

AD1.local
AD2.local

Both forests have trust relationship enabled.
I have a resource "X" on AD1 that is only accessible to the "Marketing" group situated within AD1. This resource is shared over the network and accessible through SMB to all the users of the Marketing group within AD1.
I have a computer on AD2 with Administrator Privilege called BossPC.AD2.local.
Our file security software runs on BossPC on AD2.local. Now, BossPC.AD2.local wants to run a routine scan over the resources accessible only to the Marketing group of users in AD1.local.
My approach in writing a C++ Windows API application (to which I am fairly new):

Access the token for a user in the Marketing group in AD1.local through LogonUser()

Gain token privileges for the current calling thread using ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()

Access resource and the relevant attributes using various File APIs like CreateFile(), GetExtendedAttributes(), etc


Code excerpt:
HANDLE token = NULL;

bool authenticate() {
 
    bool bSuccess{ false };
    DWORD logonType{ LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE };
    DWORD logonProvider{ LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 };
 
    cout << endl<< "Current process token: " << GetCurrentThreadToken() << endl; // Current token
 
    bSuccess = LogonUser(L"administrator",
        L"ad2.local",
        L"pwd1234$$",
        logonType,
        logonProvider,
        &token);
 
    if (bSuccess) {
        cout << endl << "Got token from LogonUser : " << token << endl; // Token from LogonUser
 
 
        bSuccess = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            wprintf(L"\nImpersonateLoggedOnUser failed with 0x%d", GetLastError());
        }
 
        cout << endl << "After impersonation token: " << GetCurrentThreadToken() << endl; // Impersonated token
 
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
            L"\\\\resourcedc.ad2.local\\SYSVOL\\",
            GENERIC_READ,
            FILE_SHARE_READ,
            nullptr,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
            nullptr
        );
 
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            cout << endl << "CreateFile failed with 0x" << GetLastError();
        }
        else {
            cout << endl << "CreateFile success: " << hFile;
        }
 
        BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION fileInfo;
        if (GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, &fileInfo)) {
            cout << endl << "File information: " << fileInfo.dwFileAttributes;
        }
        else {
            cout << endl << "GetFileInformationByHandle failed with 0x" << GetLastError();
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << endl << "LogonUser failed with 0x" << GetLastError();
    }
 
cleanup:
    if (token) {
        CloseHandle(token);
        token = nullptr;
    }
    return bSuccess;
 
}
 
 
int main()
{
    authenticate();
    RevertToSelf();
    return 0;
}

I keep getting error "0x5" - Access Denied.
My expectation is to get the handle of the resource to start with.

are administrator@ad2.local is member of Marketing group ? (which at all not exist in ad2.local) if not - why you wait that it got access to file which is only accessible to the Marketing group

Absolutely, "... token for a user in the Marketing group..." which is indicative of the fact that it is a member of Marketing group. As a matter of fact, I am able to do the same through explorer.exe by navigating to L"\\resourcedc.ad2.local\SYSVOL\" and using the same credentials that I am supplying above in the LogonUser API.
